# What's wrong with my R function for computing conditional means?

Tags: r

I've recently begun teaching myself R, and decided to try to create a function that calculates the mean of a variable in a data frame conditional on another variable in the same data frame equalling some value. Here is my code:

```
conditional.mean <- function( df, tv, cvar, cval ) {
  col1 <- df$tv
  col2 <- df$svar
  subdf <- data.frame( col1, col2 )

  tv.cond <- subdf[ which(col2==cval), 1 ]

  x <- mean( tv.cond )

  return( x )
}
```

`df` is the data frame, `tv` is the target variable whose conditional mean is to be computed, `cvar` is the variable used in the condition, and `cval` is the value to be checked for `cvar`.

When I run the code above, the function outputs `NA` and gives the following warning: "`In mean.default(tv.cond) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`." I don't understand why it is saying this, since tv.cond should be a vector of values of the target variable where `cvar` = `cval`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The tv.cond may contains NA values. You should check this first

Comment: `mean(tv.cond, na.rm = TRUE, ...)` might help !

Comment: `df$tv` and `df$var` will always resolve to `NULL`

Comment: Try `col1 <- df[,tv]` and `col2 <- df[,cvar]`.

Comment: Also, `mean(df[tv == cval, tv])` seems plenty clean for these purposes. A custom function probably isn't helping your readability that much.

Comment: @Adam, I agree, but I think you meant `df$cvar==cval`.

Comment: Your code might work, but I think there is a typo. Don't you mean `col2 <- df$cvar` instead of `col2 <- df$svar` ? That said, I think the function is far more complicated than it needs to be -- I think it can be a 1-liner.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, everyone! I am a total newb to R so I was using this more as a learning example than anything I would actually want to use. But, I have learned that Adam's suggestion of `mean(df[df$cvar == cval, tv])` would work quite well. Thanks again!